# How to install Django in a virtual environment Python (Windows 7) from a local computer folder from a terminal?

Tags: python

When installing Django in a Python 3.7 virtual environment (Windows 7), the package downloads from the Internet. But sometimes it happens that there is no access to the Internet. And if, for example, the installation package is located in the C: \ python_works \ Django-2.2.5.tar.gz folder on the computer, is it possible to install Django in the Python 3.7 virtual environment from this folder and how to do it, if possible? Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the Django Source [here](https://github.com/django/django). After you have downloaded it, you need to build a .whl file from it. More information on how to do that can be found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/executable-package-pip-install).

You can then install the local .whl file by entering: `pip install path/to/foo.whl`.

Edit: You could as well just download the .whl file from [here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/9f/a56f7893b1280e5019482260e246ab944d54a9a633a01ed04683d9ce5078/Django-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl), instead of building your own.

Comment: My problem was solved. Thanks a lot. This is a great community.